# Is there a way to put my navbar in front of everything?

Tags: html, codepen

Hello i am making a website that has a Navbar, but I have discovers that when I scroll down one of the divs overlap the Navbar. Here's The code:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="404.html"><button class=nav>Home</button></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><button class=nav>Contact Us</button></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><button class=nav>Web Development</button></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><button class=nav>Editing</button></a></li>
```

```
.nav {
border: none;
padding-left: 25px;
padding-right: 25px;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 25px;
background-color: black;
color: white;
border-radius: 100px;
transition: 1s;
z-index: 999;
}

.nav:hover {
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
 transition: 1s;
}`
```

View On Codepen

https://codepen.io/adsnipers/pen/PdNOYx?editors=1100#0

[Div appears over navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhsIi.png)

Comment: You might want to take a look at the z-index CSS property: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Use `z-index` css for positioning, Its minimum value is 1 and maximum is 999, `z-index:1` mins backward, `z-index:999` topper

Comment: You codepen seems to work already. Did you achieve what you were looking for?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can give z-index : 10000 to your navbar

Answer (score -2):

Just add this line to CSS file.

```
z-index: 999;
```

See this link for more info [MDN Docs - z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)